# Allow dev to specify the return type that depends upon input parameters at run time in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-utility

I'm wondering what options TypeScript has here. I am writing a database query helper, trying to add as much typing as possible. I have a table, MyTable with 3 fields

```
type MyTable = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

I want a function that will allow the user to specify which fields to select from the table and then return an array of objects containing just those selected fields.

I got this far:

```
async QueryDatabaseTable<T = keyof MyTable> (fieldsToReturn: T): Promise<T[]> {
   dbClient.query('myTable').select(Object.keys(fieldsToReturn));
}
```

So I call `QueryDatabaseTable<MyTable>(['name', 'age'])`
I would expect back an array of objects like:

```
[{name: 'Romano', age: 33}, {name: 'Geoff', age: 39}]
```

There is no id, because it wasn't specified.

Basically I want the contract to say whatever the dev passes in to `fieldsToReturn`, they can expect back an array of objects with `fieldsToReturn` as the keys.

You obviously wont know until runtime what the dev chooses, but we do know the possible types they can choose from - the keys of `MyTable`. I'm stuck on how to express that in typescript.

I feel I am mixing run-time and compile-time decisions. I believe **if** we know the exact fields we want at compile time we can have very strong typing. However, we won't always know exact fields passed in until runtime (user choose fields in a frontend UI when creating a report). However, in the latter case, I believe we can still express that the output of the function should be an array of objects, with keys specified in the `fieldsToReturn` parameter, even if we do not know the exact fields.

My fallback is to try do something like

```
export type KeysToArrays<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K][]
  }

async QueryDatabaseTable (fieldsToReturn: KeysToArrays<MyTableFields>): Promise<Partial<MyTableFields>[]> {
   dbClient.query('myTable').select(fieldsToReturn);
}
```

but that doesn't tie the output type to the input (string[]).

Comment: Why have you used `Object.keys(fieldsToReturn)`? Isn't `fieldsToReturn` supposed to be an array?

Comment: Write the example input and output values, otherwise hard to understend

Comment: The `typescript-typings` tag is inappropriate; please consider removing it.  Also: could you provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE?  It would be very helpful.  If you decide to [edit] the code to do this and want me to take another look, mention @jcalz in a comment. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz. removed and updated

Comment: If I look at [that code](https://tsplay.dev/w6v6ew) in a standalone IDE, I'm not sure what to do because I don't know what `dbClient.query` is and what arguments `select()` expects.  It probably doesn't expect `Object.keys(fieldsToReturn)` if `fieldsToReturn` is really an array like `['name', 'age']`, since `Object.keys['name', 'age']` is something like `['0','1']`.  For a [mre], the only issues present should be the ones you're asking about, otherwise it is, at the very least, distracting.

Comment: I suspect the *typings* would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nl2gGW), but the rest of the code in the example is just confusing. What should we do here?

Comment: select does indeed take an array of fields. I am meant to be passing in ['name', 'age'] into the select function. Apologies if that was not clear. I believe the TS playground you linked did manage to solve my question. Thank you! I am left with one more issue, this time here is a link to the code https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc. I introduced a new parameter, `fieldsToFilter`, but now it seems `fieldsToReturn` and `fieldsToFilter` must contain the same keys and I'm not seeing where that constraint comes from.

Comment: Seems my link it broken. Stack overflow complains when I share the ts playrgound url (says it's too long) and then complains when i try to use bitly to shorten it (says don't use shortened links). How did you do it?

Comment: @jcalz I've now posted an answer my own question. Thank you again for your help

Comment: I was only notified of this last message since only this one had @jcalz in it.  ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after @jcalz's help, I was able to piece together what I really wanted

My ultimate goal was to write a generic handler to querying a single database query for specific values (not range based).

Given I start with my table, MyTable:

```
type MyTable = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    age: number
}
```

I wanted to be able to construct a query object like

```
queryConfig = {
  tableName: 'my_table',
  filterFields = {'name': ['barbora', 'sandy'] },
  returnFields = ['name', 'age']
}
```

This should find all rows with the values *barbora* and *sandy*

For simplicity you can ignore the next type, it is used to allow filterFields to accept multiple values

```
type FieldsToArrays<Table> = {
  [Field in keyof Table]: Table[Field][]
}
```

This is my query queryConfig type:

```
type QueryTableConfig<Table> = {
    tableName: string,
    filterFields: Partial<FieldsToArrays<Table>>,
    returnFields: (keyof Table)[]
}
```

And here is putting it all together

```
async function QueryTable<Table, Return = { [Field in keyof Table]: Table[Field] }
> (config: QueryTableConfig<Table>): Promise<Return[]> {
  console.log(config.filterFields);
  console.log(config.returnFields);
  
  const query = dbQuery<Return>.select(config.returnFields);
  Object.keys(config.filterFields).forEach(f => {
    query.whereIn(f, config.filterFields[f])
  });
  return query.execute();
}
```

And then executing it. We specify the table's type (MyTable) as a type parameter when invoking the function

```
QueryTable<MyTable>({
  tableName: 'test',
  returnFields: ['id', 'name'],
  filterFields: {
    name:  ['Ramano', 'Geoff'],
    id: ['some-random-uuid']
    }
});
```

As said it won't do range based comparisons, but for many of my queries that is fine

Thanks again for @jcalz's initial solution - set me on the right path